# Batch Minting using SuSquares ERC721 method

Tags: solidity, remix, batch

William Entriken's method of batch minting NFT's seems like the best approach.  When deploying his Susquares contract on rinkeby testnet it doesn't seem to work.. The totalsupply() and tokenuri() functions work on remix IDE but the NFT's dont get picked up by opensea and I can't find any tokens on etherscan.  Any ideas?  (would love a response from the god Entriken himself! ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Susquares doesn’t batch mint, it mints on-demand. On Remix `totalsupply()` and `tokenuri()` work because they are coded to be independent of minting status, see `totalsupply()` code below. Etherscan and Opensea probably rely on events to discover tokens, and with a freshly deployed Susquares contract nothing is minted or transferred. If you transfer a couple of squares I'm guessing they will show up on Etherscan and Opensea.

```
uint256 private constant TOTAL_SUPPLY = 10000;

function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
    return TOTAL_SUPPLY;
}
```